# Facebook API call- "This API version is deprecated"

Tags: api, facebook

I'm trying to call to Photo.upload on the the Facebook API server. As far as I can tell the code to construct the call is good but I can't understand the responce I'm getting back from the server. As far as I can see, this call is ment to work and other people don't get this problem. I can only reason that something is wrong with the code. The commented stuff is an artifact of me trying different things to get a different responce from the server. The original code that I've changed was in part taken from an example of how to do this which I couldn't get to work either really:

http://www.jaisenmathai.com/blog/2008/11/27/using-the-facebook-api-to-upload-photos/

Server Responce:

> 12  This API version is deprecated    method  photos.upload    api_key  b92cee19a33c861275bfce4695896e44    call_id  1250194789.61    garden_jpg  /var/www/vivaladan/pictureyourselfhull/garden.jpg    v  0    sig  896ee95339cad24ce7e64a05ca764123

**Code**:

```
$key = b92cee19a33c861275bfce4695896e44;
$ver = 1.0;
$cid = microtime(true);
$uid = BIGINT;
$file= "garden.jpg";

$args = array(
  //amethod => photos.upload,
  v => $ver,
  api_key => $key,
  //uid => $uid,
  call_id => $cid,
  //format => XML
);

$args[basename($file)] = realpath($file); 
signRequest($args,$sec);

$postString = "";
foreach($args as $index => $value) {
$postString .= $index ."=".$value."&";
}
$postString = trim($postString, '&');


$ch = curl_init();
$url = "http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=photos.upload";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postString);
$data = curl_exec($ch);

echo $data;

function signRequest(&$args, $secret){
  ksort($args);
  $sig = "";
  foreach($args as $k => $v){
    $sig .= $k . '=' . $v;
  }
  $sig .= $secret;
  $args[sig] = md5($sig);
}
```

Comment: Uhg, that interface is soooo not RESTful.  Sorry, I know it's not related to your comment, but when they embed a method is a POST call to a generic URL and call it REST it just keeps sowing the seeds of SOAP/RPC...

Comment: http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=photos.upload is a perfectly valid unique URI. Who says REST requires mod_rewrite nice URLs?

Comment: @ceejayoz the reason it's not RESTful is that the same one URI is used for everything. Resources must have their own unique URIs - the query parameters do not count as part of the URI. They are the query parameters of that URI. URIs with query strings are not cached, so this is significant. This is RPC, through-and-through.

Comment: @ceejayoz I suggest you go and read Fielding's dissertation on REST, since you clearly have misconceptions about what REST is and isn't. There's a lot of misinformation out there on REST, which you've no doubt absorbed.

Comment: Someone remove the [rest] tag from this please. @Gandalf this is shocking how blatantly RPC and SOAP-like this API is, yet FB still calls it a "REST server".. geez. Terrible.

Comment: Query parameters do count as part of the URI, or http://example.com/article?id=12345 would be the same as http://example.com/article?id=12344. That is clearly not the case.

Comment: You don't get it. Those have the same URI, with different query parameters. As defined by HTTP.

Comment: Oh? RFC 3986 appears to disagree. Section 3.4 defines the query as one of the components of a URI. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.4

Comment: You're right, thanks for the link. However, it's still misusing the query component. Specifying things like 'version' in the headers is so RPC.

Comment: I thought REST methods are `GET`, `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE`. There was no `photos.upload`...

Comment: What do you know. They had a `photos.get` pseudo-method also. Anyway, the API is deprecated so I guess is OK.

Answer (score 2):

Rest API call is not working anymore.
Try [GraphApi](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's because you're using `$ver = 0.0;` - there's no 0.0 version of the API.

Comment: I was trying different version numbers to see if that made a difference. It was originally 1.0. I've changed it back in the code sample

Answer (score 0):

try using api.new.facebook.com API URL instead